# Crystal Report Showing data multiple times in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, ms-access-2007

My code is as below

Public Class AutoReportForm
Dim con1 = Form1.con1
Dim cmd1, cmd2 As OleDbCommand
Dim adp1, adp2 As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dtb1, dtb2, dtb3, dtb4, dtb5 As New DataTable
Dim myrpt As New ReportDocument
Dim CrFormatTypeOptions As New PdfRtfWordFormatOptions()
Dim txt As String = Form1.txt
Dim ds As New DataSet()

```
Sub viewdata()
    con1.open()
    Dim query As String = "Select * from AUTO_AND_RECIPE where AUTO_BATCH_UNIQUE_CODE = '" + txt + "'"
    cmd2 = New OleDbCommand(query, con1)
    adp2 = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd2)
    adp2.Fill(dtb2)


    cmd1 = New OleDbCommand("Select * from PROCESS where AUTO_BATCH_UNIQUE_CODE_1 = '" + txt + "'", con1)
    adp1 = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1)
    adp1.Fill(dtb1)
    con1.Close()
    con1.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub AutoReportForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    dtb1.Clear()
    dtb2.Clear()
    myrpt.Load("F:\VB2022\SCADAReport\Debug\AutoRpt.rpt")
    'TextBox1.Text = txt
    viewdata()

    myrpt.Database.Tables("AUTO_AND_RECIPE").SetDataSource(dtb2)
    myrpt.Database.Tables("PROCESS").SetDataSource(dtb1)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Nothing
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myrpt
End Sub
```

End Class

[This is image of my PROCESS table's datagrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deN9X.png)

[This image is showing my crystal report is showing it multiple times[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaNoN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you need to add a JOIN condition between the tables.

Without a JOIN condition, every record in Table1 is free to join to every record in Table2.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response, but I would like to share additional information or observation. In AUTO_AND_RECIPE table, if Auto_Batch_Unique_Code repeat then the report get repeated. e.g if  Auto_Batch_Unique_Code is abc-123 appears thrice in table then the data from PROCESS table appears thrice.

Comment: That is exactly the expected behavior if you don't have a proper join condition.  Without a join condition, every record from Table 1 gets joined to every record in Table 2.